# Enable line numbering for directories

Tags: vimrc, autocmd, netrw, line-numbers

When viewing a directory (using `:Explore`, for example), I would like to see line numbers. I can run `:set number` after opening the directory, and that works, but I can't get `number`ing to turn on by default (using e.g. configuration in my `.vimrc` file).

I have tried adding variations of the following to my `.vimrc` file, but none seem to work:

```
:autocmd FileType netrw set number
:autocmd FileType * setlocal number
:autocmd BufEnter * setlocal number
```

Here is a reference to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37807995/4256346) regarding numbering for help files. The solution to that question does not work in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to `:help netrw`:

```
 *g:netrw_bufsettings*  the settings that netrw buffers have
            (default) noma nomod nonu nowrap ro nobl
```

So I would try

```
" $MYVIMRC
let g:netrw_bufsettings = 'noma nomod nu nowrap ro nobl'
```

This can also be found at `:help netrw-P19`

Comment: This works. Thanks very much! When all else fails, read the instructions I suppose.